# Homogeneity of finite simple groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

According to [A complete classification of finite homogeneous groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/F8C259D47097C6F9C581DEB7AB0F9916/S0004972700036431a.pdf/div-class-title-a-complete-classification-of-finite-homogeneous-groups-div.pdf), the finite simple groups $G$ which are homogeneous (meaning every isomorphism between subgroups extends to an automorphism of $G$) are precisely all of the Abelian cases plus the two smallest non-Abelian cases. Out of the remaining groups, I wondered which came closest, in the sense of the fraction of all isomorphisms between the group’s subgroups that extend to automorphisms of it. I have termed this the group’s *homogeneity*.

> **Question:** is there a highest possible value the homogeneity of a finite simple group can take on while remaining less than one? If so, which group or groups achieve it?

Comment: I was wondering how you are counting "isomorphisms between the group's subgroups"? Are you literally thinking of counting all pairs of subgroups, and then all isomorphisms between them, or would you "count up to conjugacy"? I guess $A_6$ is the obvious candidate to give a maximum possible value less than one... My guess would be that the answer to the question would be YES -- I'm thinking that the number of isomorphisms would be dominated by those between abelian subgroups and as soon as you start getting lots of aut-conjugacy classes of such things, the homogeneity would drop quickly.

Comment: I don't know how to prove this though!! It might be icky...

Comment: It looks like PSL(3,4) and PSU(3,5) are also candidates.